# .back and sort function

Tags: c++, sorting

I am a complete beginner to c++ and for an assignment I have been asked to sort a text file of superheroes and output them to another text file e.g.

Unsorted.txt

Deadpool_8

Phoenix_9

Toad_4

Jubilee_3

alphabetically and numerically.

I have attempted to use .back for each line of string for the numerical sorting although it simply will not accept it and returns an error (which I have included in the code) as well as, whilst it is happy to write to console in full with cout attempting to write to text file results in only the last line of string e.g.

Toad_4

(all my mistakes have been commented out and it is currently only sorting alphabetically)

I'm paranoid about asking the same question as someone else, but I have not been able to find anything which solves my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
// Empty vector holding names from file
vector<string> names;
string word;
string number;
string filename;
string sortChoice;
string lastChar;
bool alphaSortFinished = false; //bool added to prevent unnecessary looping
bool sortFinished = false;

void sortNumerically()
{
//word = word.back;         returns this error
/*Error 1   error C3867:         'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::back': function call missing argument list; use 
'&std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::back' to create a pointer to member  
d:\visual studio 2013\assessment one mdu118\strings, classes assessment one\source.cpp  20  1   Strings, Classes Assessment One*/


cout << "Please specify the file you would like to open\n" << endl;
cin >> filename;

// Read names from specified file
ifstream inFile(filename);

while (!inFile && sortFinished == false)
{
    cout << "Unable to open file\n";
    inFile.close();
    sortNumerically();
}

while (getline(inFile, word)) //get lines of the string, store them in string word;
{
    names.push_back(word);
}

sort(names.begin(), names.end());

// Loop to print names
for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
{
    //ofstream writeToFile;
    //writeToFile.open("NumericalSort.txt");
    //writeToFile << names[i] << '\n';
    //writeToFile.close();
    cout << names[i] << '\n';
}
sortFinished = true;
inFile.close();
}
```

sorry there's probably a lot of crap that refers to other functions I didn't include. Am I taking the wrong route?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

To populate `vector` of strings

```
vector<string> names;
ifstream inFile(filename);
copy(istream_iterator<string>(inFile), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(names));
```

To sort lexicographically

```
sort(names.begin(), names.end());
```

To sort numerically

```
sort(names.begin(), names.end(), cmpr());
```

`cmpr` is a custom comparator defined to compare numerical part of strings.

To get the numerical part of string, use

```
int num = stoi(s.substr(s.find_last_of('_') + 1));
```

An example in `C++11`

```
sort(names.begin(), names.end(), [](const string & a, const string & b) {
    int ia = stoi(a.substr(a.find_last_of('_') + 1));
    int ib = stoi(b.substr(b.find_last_of('_') + 1));
    return ia < ib;
});
```

See http://ideone.com/1Wcnvq demo

Comment: I don't think using less<> will give numerical sorting for strings.

Comment: @Jagannath I was in the middle of updating it, anyway thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @emoney666 Perhaps you can accept the answer if your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Read the names from the file to `std::vector<string>`.

```
sort(names.begin(), names.end()).
```

Now,

```
sort(names.begin(), names.end(), comparator)
```

The *comparator* should take 2 strings as arguments and compare the number part of the strings.

Comment: Thanks @volerag, I posted this from an app and hence the formatting is not good.